# Social authentication from both iOS app and backend server

Tags: ios, authentication, swift3, oauth-2.0, spring-social

I am trying to implement a login flow, which involves both iOS app and server integration. Other than social authentication, application support email/password authentication as well. Once successful authentication server application send auth_token which can be used in subsequent API calls.

My social login flow as follows :

- iOS application initiate social login by retrieving a code as response type from the authentication provider.
- Retrieved code send to server application, so it verifies with the social authentication provider and (create an account if not exist) authenticate the user.
- Successful authentication will generate auth token as normal (email / password) authentication and send back to the mobile application.

Once successful authentication, both approaches mobile application receives auth_token.

I tried to implement this flow using OAuthSwift library and spring-social. I think backend part is working fine. But OAuthSwift doesn't seems to support retrieving just the code. (I opened a issue in their Github repo)

My Questions are:

1. If you see any problem with this approach?
2. What are the other Good Swift frameworks, which supports retrieving authentication code as response_type

Answer (score 0):

You will lose the connection to your social login. Because you switch to your OAuth mechanism, you will not have any notice if the user changed something in there social account.

Thats ok, if you not rely on any off his data, for example his e-mail address.

But keep that in mind.